# Pigeonhole Principle: 5 integers from 1 to 8, some pair has sum 9.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, pigeonhole-principle

The question is:

> Let $A = \{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$. If five integers are selected from $A$, must at least one pair of the integers have a sum of $9$?

The book explains the solution by dividing the number into $4$ disjoint subsets and pointing out that if the numbers in each set are added together, they result in a sum of $9$: $\{1,8\}, \{2,7\}, \{3,6\}, \{4,5\}$.

Thus, if you pick $5$ numbers, you will inevitably find a pair, whose sum will equal to $9$.

I don't get it. When the book asks to select $5$ numbers from $A$, I can pick $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$. Then from there, I can pick two integers like $1$ and $2$, whose sum does not equal to $9$. What am I not getting here?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: its saying when you pick any 5 elements, you have some pair in that set of 5 elements whose sum is 9. In the set of 5 elements you picked, $4+5 = 9$

Comment: Of course *some* pairs, indeed many pairs, will not have sum $9$. But in your example, $4+5=9$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that group of 5 you selected, the pair 4 and 5 sum to 9.  Obviously, not all pairs from that set of 5 elements will sum to 9, the problem just asks if there must be at least one that does.

Answer (score 8):

Let's play a game:

First, *you* pick five numbers from among $\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8\}$.

Then *I* get to pick two of the five numbers you picked. If I pick two that add up to $9$, then *I* win; if the two I pick don't add up to $9$, then you win.

What the problem says is that I can **always** win, no matter which five numbers you pick during your turn.

In other words, you get to pick the five numbers, but you don't also get to specify which two you want to add up to 9.

Comment: I don't really understand how to apply pigeonhole here!

Comment: @Avra: The answer explained the misconception in the original poster about what the problem says. The pigeonhole principle is used to show that if you have five numbers from among these, the sum of at least two of them will add up to $9$. The pigeonhole principle is applied by looking at the partition of the original set into $\{1,8\}$, $\{2,7\}|$, $\{3,6\}$, and $\{4,5\}$. You must pick five elements, so you will pick at least two from the same two-element set, which will give you the sum equal to $9$.