# Elementary Probability and Statistics

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Choose any $38$ different natural numbers less than $1000$.

Prove that among the selected numbers there exists at least two whose difference is at most $26$.

Comment: I don't think this question has much to do with probability or statistics, but see, for example, [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/q/91635/15941) to get an idea on how this one can be approached.  Maybe you should edit the tags accordingly.

Answer (score 3):

Arrange the numbers in increasing order. The smallest number is $\ge 1$. If all differences between consecutive numbers are $27$ or more, then the biggest number is $\ge 1+ (27)(37)$, which is $1000$.